# Oracle SQL: create database

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am relatively new to Oracle SQL Developer, and I am trying to create a Covid database.

My code below is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Cases 
(
    ReportID INT NOT NULL,
    Dates DATE,
    IslandName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Casestodate INT NOT NULL,
    NewCases INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT cases_pk PRIMARY KEY(ReportID)
);
```

The table is created; however, when I attempt to insert data, I get the following error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.CASES_PK) violated

My theory is that the `ReportID` is duplicated for several `IslandNames`. For example there is `ReportID = 209` seen 8 times in the database.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That would do it.

Comment: I agree with your explanation.  Check your insert script for duplicates.

Comment: you can use Composite Key.  e.g. CONSTRAINT cases_pk PRIMARY KEY(ReportID, IslandName).